# How to implement Command Pattern for CRUD operations

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a UI with Create , Update , Delete and Select Operations , so for this i thought to design it using Command Pattern

**MyServlet**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
     throws ServletException,IOException
    {

InsertCommand insertCommnd = new InsertCommand();
DeleteCommand deleteCommnd = new DeleteCommand();
```

// Create the DTO Employee with request parameters and pass it to invoker

```
if(req.getParameter("action").equals("insert"))

  Invoker invoker = new Invoker();

 invoker.setCommand(insertCommnd );
 invoker.pressButton(emp);


    }
```

**//**Invoker****

```
public class Invoker
{
    private Command command;

    public void setCommand(Command command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }


    public void pressButton(Employee emp)
    {
        command.execute(emp);
    }

}
```

//**Command**.java

```
public interface Command
{
public void execute();
}
```

**DeleteCommand**.java

```
public DeleteCommand implements Command
{   

Employee emp;

public DeleteCommand(Employee emp)
{

this.emp = emp;
}

public void execute()
{
// SQL Query to delete Records
}

}
```

**InsertCommand.java**

```
 public InsertCommand implements Command
    {
     Employee emp ;
    public InsertCommand(Employee emp)
    {

    this.emp = emp;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
    // SQL Query to insert Records
    }

    }
```

Similarly there is a Update Records command

My question is , how can i handle this in case of Select Operations as it returns a ArrayList from Database ?

Also please share your ideas on this design ,as i am new to Designing Software .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right approach meaning that you are trying to use design patterns in your code.
In your case you are using the wrong pattern.You should be using a `DAO` pattern instead.

But saying wrong doesn't mean that your approach can't be used.It is just that `DAO` is the standard for DB.

In your case your problem is that your `execute` method returns `void` and you need a method (extra) that returns a `List`.

You could create a second method for select that returns a `List` and give it a generic name and in your other commands simply throw an `UnsupportedMethod` exception

E.g.

```
public interface Command 
{ 
public void execute(); 
public List fetch();  
}
```

Comment: This is the "straightforward \"slap everything\"" approach I mention in my answer. It is indeed much more common than CQRS and perfectly valid for most cases. There are instances where CQRS is a better fit, so "the wrong pattern" is a bit too strong IMO (my own "slap everything" wording might be a bit too harsh as well). Both are valid, DAO is easier and much more common.

Comment: @user384706 Thanks , so you mean to say that go for Command Pattern in case if the return types will be of same type know ?

Comment: @yyyi777 a nice, solid approach is to make the command classes implement `java.util.concurrent.Future` (the easiest way is to extend from or wrap in `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`).

Comment: @yyyi777:In the command pattern you pass the commands to the queue and then you process the queue i.e. call the processing method of each command e.g. execute.The idea is that you don't know (and don't care) what command is currently under execution but you know that all commands can start processing in the same way e.g. via execute.In general the approach for DB is the DAO. Read on DAO

Comment: Could you please tell a scenarion where a command pattern is suitable , bcaz when i googled i found only the client and waitress examples of restaurant

Comment: So with the information you mentioned i can think of Command Pattern a MessageDrivenBean processing items on a Queue ?? but i cant think of any scenario where a Command pattern would be useful ?

Comment: @yyyi777 the CQRSInfo.com website I linked to has extensive documentation on the subject. One case where it might be useful is if you are using master/slave replication for scalability. Another case is if you need to be able to "go back in time" and view your data as it was at some point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider building your SELECT operations as traditional method invocations on a DAO or service class, while modeling CREATE, INSERT and DELETE as commands sent to a command queue. This is an architectural pattern known as [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](http://www.cqrsinfo.com/).

CQRS has a somewhat higher initial complexity than straightforward "slap everything on a DAO object" imperative programming, but it can offer advantages that are very hard to achieve otherwise, especially when the commands themselves are stored in the data store (in an append-only fashion). One of these is the ability to view the state of your data at any point in time.